# Add a common view for all view controllers in UITabbarController

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to develop something like the playback bar in Apple Music. A common view that appears at the bottom of all the view controllers of a UITabbarContoller. Is there any idea or a best practice to achieve this ?
[image]

Well, I'll just put down my personal solution

1. subclass a view controller for the common view.
2. attach the view controller as the child view controller of the tab bar controller.

I don't really like embedding a view controller to the tab bar controller. Just let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you tell me from where you got this song list , i.e. from which api?

Comment: @Dh1_Bh1 It's just a screen cap of the Apple Music.

Comment: bunnyshell , did you find any solution ? if yes then please share it.. i also want to do this

Comment: @RaviJSS As I mentioned in the question description, I basically create a playbackBarViewController, make it the child viewController of the Tab bar Controller and attach its view to the view of the tab bar. And you also need to handle the offset of views underneath the playback bar otherwise the bar will overlap the bottom of them.

Comment: can you please provide sample code , it will be helpful for me

Comment: @RaviJSS I'd like to help. But I didn't do iOS programming for a long time. The attaching playback bar view part should be easy, there is some doc your can refer to [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

Comment: @RaviJSS For the offset handling, you can change the bottom constraint of the tab bar view controller's containing view and do layout once the playback bar is shown/hidden. If all the containing views are scrolling view, you can change the offset of the scrolling view as well (which is my case). And you can implement those nasty things through method swizzling if you like.

Comment: Thanks @bunnyshell

Comment: Hi @bunnyshell
Does your viewcontroller slides to bigger one from bottom to top?

Answer (score 3):

`UITabBar` has `UINavigationController` which has all the separate `UIViewController`s. If you want this view in each tab, then best way to do it is to add it on top of the `UINavigationController`s view. It will appear on top of whatever is in `UINavigationController`.

Comment: How can I access the `UINavigationController` you are talking about?

Comment: [self.navigationcontroller.view addSubview:yourView]

Comment: well, there is no guarantee that there is a `UINavigationController`... the `navigationcontroller` property of a `UIViewController` refers to the possible navigation controller that the view controller is embedded in.

Answer (score 1):

You can add that view to window as subview

```
 [self.window addSubview:vw];
```

with a tag

```
 vw.tag = 10000;
```

so that you can see that view throughout the app

Comment: I don't really want to see it throughout the app. Just for the view controllers inside the uitabbarcontroller. For like views presented modally outside, that view shouldn't be seen.

Comment: You can hide with
 UIView *vw=(UIView*)[window viewWithTag:1000];
    vw.hidden=YES;

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
Use segue to go from one page to another rather than using navigation controller.

```
 - (IBAction)YourButton:(id)sender
   {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
   } 

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
      if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueSearchList"])
      {
           // Do what you want to do
      }

   }
```

By doing this,your tab bar will look like as it is in first page

Answer (score 0):

Have a ParentViewontroller class which has tabbar at the bottom and inherit this class to the view controllers which needs a tabbar and handle things.

Answer (score 0):

You could make xib for your view or a class inherited from UIView and add it in whatever controller you want.